# Extreme Hang In A Repeat Loop

Tags: applescript

With my script for a Numbers table, I am experiencing an extreme (3-4 seconds per cell) hang in a repeat loop, which I believe may be caused by my use of the `copy` command, since as I understand it,`copy` creates a new reference to the value, instead of replacing the value like the `set` command would. I am unsure if its the use of the `copy` command, my Mac, or poor placement of the loop in the sequence of commands. I've tried switching the sequence of commands around which doesn't help. Other uses of a similar `copy` loop do not behave so slowly. My question is sort of a compound question. Am I asking the loop to process to much, is it misplaced, should I be using something other than `copy` or is it simply my Mac? (memory doesn't appear to be low enough to cause the hang, still 1.5gb left during the hang, nothing except Numbers and the script running) To sum it up, how can I solve the hang issue?

The portion of the loop where the hang begins is below

```
-- This is where the extreme hang begins

repeat with x from 1 to (count rows) - 2
    repeat with y from 1 to count monthNames
        copy incrementDates(y) of me to {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
        set monthStart to theDateString
        set monthEnd to theMonthIndex & "/" & monthLengthInDays & "/" & theYear as text
        set theFormula to "=SUMIFS(Amount,Category,A,Date, \">=" & monthStart & "\",Date, \"<=" & monthEnd & "\")"
        set value of cell (y + 1) of row (x + 1) to theFormula
    end repeat
end repeat

-- Extreme hang ends and script continues normally
```

The full script for reference is here, in case its a compounded issue of my other `copy` usage.

```
set moneyInHeaders to {"Last Name", "First Name", "Receipt Number", "Payment", "Date", "Office", "City", "Referral Name"}
set locationList to {"Location 1", "Location 2"}
set the monthNames to {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
set moneyOutHeaders to {"Expense", "Amount", "Date", "Category", "Item"}
set categoryItems to {"Marketing", "Software", "Tools", "Utilities", "Other"}
set thisYearName to (year of (current date)) as string
set moneyInColor to {31354, 51657, 22615}
set moneyOutColor to {59623, 20816, 14391}

tell application "Numbers"
if not (exists document 1) then make new document
tell document 1
    delete every sheet
    set the name of sheet 1 to "Money In"
    tell sheet 1
        delete every table
        set moneyInTable to make new table with properties {name:"Money In", position:{-7, 29}, width:788, column count:count moneyInHeaders, row count:14, footer row count:1, header column count:2}
        tell moneyInTable
            set locationCount to count locationList -- get count of locations
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyInColor}}
            my populateCells(moneyInTable, row 1, moneyInHeaders, false) -- fill header row values
            set value of last cell of column named "Payment" to ("=SUM(C)")
            my populateCells(moneyInTable, column named "Office", locationList, true) -- fill pop up menu values
            my formatCells(moneyInTable, column named "Payment", currency)
            my formatCells(moneyInTable, column named "Date", date and time)
            my formatCells(moneyInTable, column named "Office", pop up menu)
            delete (rows 2 through (locationCount + 1)) -- remove rows that contain values so the pop up column is empty
            repeat locationCount times -- add the rows back to keep table size
                add row below row 2
            end repeat
        end tell -- end telling moneyInTable

        -- Set locked false for now
        set totalsTable to make new table with properties {name:"Money In Totals", locked:false, position:{785, 29}, column count:2, row count:(count monthNames) + 2, header column count:1, header row count:1, footer row count:1}
        tell totalsTable
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyInColor}}
            my populateCells(totalsTable, column "A", monthNames, true)
            set value of last cell of column "A" to "Grand Total"
            set value of cell "B1" to "Totals"
            set value of last cell to ("=SUM(B)")
            tell column "B"
                repeat with x from 1 to count monthNames -- loop and increment dates for the SUMIFS formula
                    copy incrementDates(x) of me to {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
                    set monthStart to theDateString
                    set monthEnd to theMonthIndex & "/" & monthLengthInDays & "/" & theYear as text
                    set the value of cell (x + 1) to ("=SUMIFS(Payment,Date, \">=" & monthStart & "\", Date, \"<=" & monthEnd & "\")")
                end repeat
            end tell -- end telling column B
        end tell -- end telling totalsTable
    end tell -- end telling active sheet

    make new sheet with properties {name:"Money Out"}
    tell sheet 2
        delete every table
        set moneyOutTable to make new table with properties {name:"Money Out", position:{-7, 29}, width:710, column count:count moneyOutHeaders, row count:14, footer row count:1}
        tell moneyOutTable
            set catCount to count categoryItems -- get count of categoryItems
            set properties of column "A" to {width:180}
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyOutColor}}
            set value of last cell of column "B" to ("=SUM(B)")
            my populateCells(moneyOutTable, row 1, moneyOutHeaders, false) -- fill header row values
            my populateCells(moneyOutTable, column named "Category", categoryItems, true) -- fill pop up values
            my formatCells(moneyOutTable, column "A", text)
            my formatCells(moneyOutTable, column named "Amount", currency)
            my formatCells(moneyOutTable, column named "Date", date and time)
            my formatCells(moneyOutTable, column named "Category", pop up menu)
            my formatCells(moneyOutTable, column named "Item", text)
            delete (rows 2 through (catCount + 1)) -- remove rows that contain values so the pop up menu is empty
            repeat catCount times -- add the rows back to keep table size
                add row below row 2
            end repeat
        end tell -- end telling moneyOutTable

        set totalsTable to make new table with properties {name:"Money Out Totals", locked:false, position:{744, 29}, column count:2, row count:(count monthNames) + 2, header column count:1, header row count:1, footer row count:1}
        tell totalsTable
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyOutColor}}
            my populateCells(totalsTable, column "A", monthNames, true)
            set value of last cell of column "A" to "Grand Total"
            set value of cell "B1" to "Totals"
            set value of last cell to ("=SUM(B)")
            tell column "B"
                repeat with x from 1 to count monthNames -- oop and increment dates for the SUMIFS formula
                    copy incrementDates(x) of me to {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
                    set monthStart to theDateString
                    set monthEnd to theMonthIndex & "/" & monthLengthInDays & "/" & theYear as text
                    set theFormula to ("=SUMIFS(Amount,Date, \">=" & monthStart & "\", Date, \"<=" & monthEnd & "\")")
                    set the value of cell (x + 1) to theFormula
                end repeat
            end tell -- end telling column B
        end tell -- end telling totalsTable

        set summaryTable to make new table with properties {name:"Category Totals", position:{943, 29}, column count:2, row count:(catCount) + 1}
        tell summaryTable
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyOutColor}}
            set value of cell "B1" to "Totals"
            my populateCells(summaryTable, column "A", categoryItems, true)
            my formatCells(summaryTable, column "B", currency)
            tell column 2
                repeat with x from 2 to the count of cells
                    set theFormula to ("=SUMIFS(Amount,Category,A)")
                    set the value of cell x to theFormula
                end repeat
            end tell -- end telling column 2
        end tell -- end telling summaryTable

        -- Extreme hang starts on this table, specifically below where noted

        set breakDownTable to make new table with properties {name:"Expenses By Month", column count:(count monthNames) + 1, row count:(count categoryItems) + 2, header column count:1, footer row count:1, header row count:1}
        tell breakDownTable
            set properties of row 1 to {background color:{moneyOutColor}}
            my populateCells(breakDownTable, row 1, monthNames, true)
            my populateCells(breakDownTable, column "A", categoryItems, true)
            my formulateRow(breakDownTable, last row, "SUM")
            set selection range to range "B2:M8"
            set properties of selection range to {format:currency}
            set value of last cell of column "A" to "Total"

--***** This is where the extreme hang begins

            repeat with x from 1 to (count rows) - 2
                repeat with y from 1 to count monthNames
                    copy incrementDates(y) of me to {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
                    set monthStart to theDateString
                    set monthEnd to theMonthIndex & "/" & monthLengthInDays & "/" & theYear as text
                    set theFormula to "=SUMIFS(Amount,Category,A,Date, \">=" & monthStart & "\",Date, \"<=" & monthEnd & "\")"
                    set value of cell (y + 1) of row (x + 1) to theFormula
                end repeat
            end repeat

--***** Extreme hang ends and script continues normally

            add column after last column -- add a totals column after everything else is done
            set totalsColumn to the last column
            tell totalsColumn
                set value of cell 1 to "Total"
                my formulateColumn(breakDownTable, totalsColumn, "SUM")
            end tell -- end telling totalsColumn
        end tell -- end telling breakDownTable
    end tell -- end telling sheet 2

    make new sheet with properties {name:"Overview"}
    tell sheet 3
        delete every table
        set cashFlowTable to make new table with properties {name:"Cashflow", column count:2, row count:(count monthNames) + 2, footer row count:1}
        tell cashFlowTable
            my populateCells(cashFlowTable, column "A", monthNames, true)
            set value of last cell of column "A" to "Grand Total"
            my formatCells(cashFlowTable, column "B", currency)
            set value of cell "B1" to "Cashflow Totals"
            set value of last cell to ("=SUM(B)")
            tell column 2
                repeat with x from 1 to count monthNames
                    set value of cell (x + 1) to ("=Money In::Money In Totals::Totals " & item x of monthNames & "−Money Out::Money Out Totals::Totals " & item x of monthNames)
                end repeat
            end tell -- end telling column 2
        end tell -- end telling cashflow table
    end tell -- end telling sheet 3
    set active sheet to first sheet
end tell -- end telling document
end tell -- end telling Numbers

using terms from application "Numbers"

to populateCells(theTable, theDirection, theListToUse, usingHeaders)
    tell theTable
        set x to 1
        if usingHeaders is true then
            repeat with x from 1 to count theListToUse
                set value of cell (x + 1) of theDirection to (item x of theListToUse)
            end repeat
        else
            repeat with x from 1 to count theListToUse
                set value of cell x of theDirection to (item x of theListToUse)
            end repeat
        end if
    end tell
end populateCells

to formatCells(theTable, theDirection, theFormat)
    tell theTable
        set theRange to ¬
            ((name of cell 2 of theDirection) & ":" & ¬
                (name of last cell of theDirection))
        set selection range to range theRange
        set properties of selection range to {format:theFormat}
    end tell
end formatCells

to colorCells(theTable, theDirection, theColor)
    tell theTable
        set theRange to ¬
            ((name of cell 2 of theDirection) & ":" & ¬
                (name of last cell of theDirection))
        set selection range to range theRange
        set properties of selection range to {background color:theColor}
    end tell
end colorCells

to formulateColumn(theTable, theColumn, theType)
    tell theTable
        tell theColumn
            repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells
                set thisRow to the row of cell i
                set rangeStart to the name of cell 2 of thisRow
                set rangeEnd to the name of cell -2 of thisRow
                set theFormula to ("=" & theType & "(" & rangeStart & ":" & rangeEnd & ")") as string
                set value of cell i to theFormula
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end formulateColumn

to formulateRow(theTable, theRow, theType)
    tell theTable
        tell theRow
            repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells
                set thisColumn to the column of cell i
                set rangeStart to the name of thisColumn
                set rangeEnd to the name of thisColumn
                set theFormula to ("=" & theType & "(" & rangeStart & ":" & rangeEnd & ")") as string
                set value of cell i to theFormula
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end formulateRow

end using terms from

to incrementDates(tempMonth)
     copy (current date) to tempDate
     set day of tempDate to 1
     set month of tempDate to tempMonth
     set theDayName to weekday of tempDate
     set theDayIndex to day of tempDate
     set theMonth to month of tempDate
     set theMonthIndex to theMonth as integer
     set theMonthName to theMonth as string
     set theYear to year of tempDate
     set theDateString to short date string of tempDate
     repeat with i from 1 to 32
         set tempDate to tempDate + (1 * days)
         if month of tempDate is not theMonth then
             set monthLengthInDays to i
             exit repeat
         end if
     end repeat
     return {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
end incrementDates
```

Comment: Try to avoid copy (current date). Use instead: set tempDate to current date

Comment: @Pat_Morita thats a little vague. No reasoning?  How would I reference my values returned from the incrementDates handler? If you're going to take the time to comment at least make it meaningful or helpful in the least. Your comment is equivalent to answering "Why does my arm hurt?" with "Use your other arm."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over your script, I've ran it and didn't experience the lag you're describing so that leaves the issue to your system or multiple test runs while writing the script.

Next as mentioned in the comments above, you can use the `set` command instead of `copy` in your `incrementDates` handler. You don't need a copy of `(current date)` each time your handler is invoked (12 times each call) so that could be changed to

```
to incrementDates(tempMonth)
     set tempDate to (current date)
     set day of tempDate to 1
     set month of tempDate to tempMonth
     set theDayName to weekday of tempDate
     set theDayIndex to day of tempDate
     set theMonth to month of tempDate
     set theMonthIndex to theMonth as integer
     set theMonthName to theMonth as string
     set theYear to year of tempDate
     set theDateString to short date string of tempDate
         repeat with i from 1 to 32
         set tempDate to tempDate + (1 * days)
         if month of tempDate is not theMonth then
             set monthLengthInDays to i
             exit repeat
         end if
     end repeat
     return {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
end incrementDates
```

from there you would still retrieve the values as you're currently doing.

Next you've also created a handler here where a handler isn't particularly needed.

```
to formatCells(theTable, theDirection, theFormat)
    tell theTable
        set theRange to ¬
        ((name of cell 2 of theDirection) & ":" & ¬
            (name of last cell of theDirection))
    set selection range to range theRange
    set properties of selection range to {format:theFormat}
end tell
end formatCells
```

The above is the same as using

```
set properties of column named "Payment" to {format:currency}
```

The difference is negligible, but my general guide is don't reinvent the wheel. You're also not using a handler where a handler could be used when creating the `totalsTable`

```
to makeMonthlyTotalsTable(theTable, theColor)
    tell theTable
        set properties of row 1 to {background color:{theColor}}
        my populateCells(totalsTable, column "A", monthNames, true)
        set value of last cell of column "A" to "Grand Total"
        set value of cell "B1" to "Totals"
        set value of last cell to ("=SUM(B)")
        tell column "B"
            repeat with x from 1 to count monthNames -- loop and increment dates for the SUMIFS formula
                copy incrementDates(x) of me to {theDayIndex, theMonthIndex, theYear, theDateString, monthLengthInDays}
                set monthStart to theDateString
                set monthEnd to theMonthIndex & "/" & monthLengthInDays & "/" & theYear as text
                set the value of cell (x + 1) to ("=SUMIFS(Payment,Date, \">=" & monthStart & "\", Date, \"<=" & monthEnd & "\")")
            end repeat
        end tell -- end telling column B
    end tell -- end telling totalsTable
end makeMonthlyTotalsTable
```

Again negligible difference and maybe opinion, but cleaner code if you plan on recreating that table in other sheets.

NOTE: I didn't test this handler, I just copied and pasted it from your script and changed the variable names to pass, but it should run fine as long as you set and declare the color name variables and switch `monthNames` to a property.

```
property monthNames : {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
```